Cannot Modify Header Information on Shortcode redirect
The wp-redirect is not working, i always get the error "cannot modify header information"
    function lwb_voucher_redeem() {
    ob_start(); // Start output buffering

    // Ausgabe des Formulars
    ?><h1>Gutscheincode Überprüfung</h1>
    <form method="post">
        <label for="code">Gutscheincode:</label>
        <input type="text" id="code" name="code" required>
        <button type="submit">Überprüfen</button>
    </form><?php

    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        
        // Abspeichern des eingegebenen Codes
        $code = sanitize_text_field($_POST["code"]);
        
        // Flag zum Überprüfen, ob ein gültiger Code gefunden wurde
        $is_valid_code = false;

        // Alle aktuellen und gültigen Satellite Codes abrufen
        $query = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type' => 'voucher',
            'post_status' => 'publish'
        ));

        while ($query->have_posts()) {
            $query->the_post();
            $post_id = get_the_ID();
            $post_title = get_the_title($post_id);
            
            if ($code == $post_title) {
                // Markiere den Code als gültig
                $is_valid_code = true;
                break; // Beende die Schleife, da ein gültiger Code gefunden wurde
            }
        }

        wp_reset_postdata();

        if ($is_valid_code) {
            // Leere den Puffer, um sicherzustellen, dass keine vorherige Ausgabe erfolgt ist
            ob_end_clean();
            //echo 'Gutscheincode gültig';
            // Weiterleitung auf eine andere Seite, wenn der Gutscheincode gültig ist
            wp_safe_redirect('http://localhost/wordpress/voucher-einloesen/');
            die;
        } else {
            // Wenn kein gültiger Code gefunden wurde, Nachricht anzeigen
            echo 'Gutscheincode ungültig';
        }
    }
    
    return ob_get_clean(); // Return the buffered output
}

add_shortcode('voucher_form', 'lwb_voucher_redeem');


Shortcodes are parsed much later than headers are sent. Impossible in plain PHP. The only way to redirect so late is JavaScript.

I add to fuxia's comment that shortcode are not here to handle form submission or redirection. to do that you can use javascript to read an endpoint of the API or you can send your form to wp-admin/wp-post.php.
